# Chrome DevTools "clear cache"... doesn't

Tags: google-chrome-devtools

Here is what I see at the start:

[image]

[image]

---

And then, after clicking "Clear Site Data" with the above options:

---

[image]

---

Why has the "Cache Storage" value barely even been touched?  How can I get rid of the 10.2 MB in there?  Where is it?

Comment: After clicking **Clear Site Data** the Usage chart should drop to 0 (no page reload or anything needed). Do you have a URL where I can reproduce? You can [submit it privately](https://docs.google.com/forms/d/1t4_hLQ-pnXfO8Gugn5W2fYd3n8xg6PvjWHg_Eb1ZfG4/edit).

Comment: Try https://www.chromestatus.com/samples @KayceBasques

Comment: I'm seeing this too. I'll see if I can figure out how to reproduce.

Comment: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=795701